# Explain a simple integration problem over a measu

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, measure-theory

$P$ is a probability measure over $X$.

$S\subset X$

$$P(S)=\frac{\int_Sf(x)dx}{\int_Xf(x)dx}$$

Is it possible to simplify:

$$\mathbb E_P[f]=\int_X f(x)P(dx)?$$

I have no idea how to make sense of this simple expression. Any explanation would help!

I think it might be easily simplified because it is unusual that the $f$ are the same in the two expressions.

Comment: Do you have something specific in mind when you’re asking to simplify the expression?

Answer (score 2):

$E_P(g)=\frac {\int_X f(x)g(x)dx} {\int_X f(x)dx }$ whenever the integral exists. Put $g=f$.